# Whats the better way to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query, I am trying to find out how many employees have a department ID assigned and how many of them have no department assigned (DepartmentID is not a Foreign Key)

```
WITH 
archive AS
(SELECT  CASE  COALESCE(tbl_Department.DepartmentID, -33) WHEN -33 THEN 'Department Not Found' ELSE 'Department Found' END  AS DepartmentStatus

FROM dbo.tbl_Employee  
WITH (NOLOCK)

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_Department
 WITH (NOLOCK)
 ON tbl_Employee.DepartmentID = tbl_Department.DepartmentID 
) 

SELECT DepartmentStatus, COUNT(DepartmentStatus) 
FROM archive


GROUP BY DepartmentStatus
```

The above query works good but it takes too long to execute. I have about a couple hundred thousand employee records and about 4000 department records.

Comment: A couple hundred thousand employees?, that's a big company

Comment: Alright whatever, the actual business detail had to be hidden so the the problem had to be mapped to Emp-Dept from the actual business scenario.

Comment: So, the problem is that there are department ids on assigned to the employee that doesn't exist on the departments table?

Comment: Some employees have DepartmentID set to NULL, And yes some Document IDs are invalid

Comment: And why the NOLOCK hints? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicated rows? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @TimSchmelter Unless, of course, *some* `DepartmentID`s are already stored as `-33`.  (hopefully not, but I've seen worse things...)

Comment: Also, why are there employees with a department_Id that doesn't appear on the department table? don't you have a foreign key?

Comment: @Zohar: The `DepartmentID` is not a foreign-key, so i assume that inconsistencies are possible, `DepartmentID` which are assigned but don't exist in `tbl_Department`. Maybe OP want to fix this issue currently.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I know it's not a foreign key, I'm just asking the OP why isn't it a foreign key... Not that joins must be made on foreign key values, but it seems that there should be a foreign key there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with avoiding the `COALESCE` function if it's not needed. I assume that `-33` is just a placeholder for `NULL`. Following is clearer and also more efficient since the optimizer can use indexes.

I would write it in this way by using `EXISTS` and no join at all:

```
WITH archive AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_Department d
                            WHERE d.DepartmentID = e.DepartmentID)
           THEN 'Department Found' 
           ELSE 'Department Not Found' END AS DepartmentStatus
    FROM   dbo.tbl_Employee WITH (NOLOCK) e
)
SELECT DepartmentStatus, Count(*) As Cnt 
FROM archive
GROUP BY DepartmentStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DepartmentID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EmployeesWithNoDepartment
FROM tbl_Department
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN d.DepartmentID IS NULL THEN 'Not Found' ELSE 'Found' END [Status],
       COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM dbo.tbl_Employee e
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_Department d ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
GROUP BY CASE WHEN d.DepartmentID IS NULL THEN 'Not Found' ELSE 'Found' END
```